# One Magento with two domains

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have a clothing website on Magento (www.mystore.com). Its backend path is www.mystore.com/admin.

I need to create multidomain backend i.e.

[www.mystore.com/admin](http://www.mystore.com/admin)

[www.mystore2.com/admin](http://www.mystore2.com/admin).

But I have to keep frontend same.

Comment: have you tried this??

Comment: @MagenX yesterday tried what?

Comment: just open admin path...

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple:

1. If you want to keep the same and one Magento you have to create an **Alias domain** in your server then you point it to your Magento root in your vhost.
2. If you want to have One Magento with **two websites**, you have to create a second website, you point your second domain to the Magento root in your v host and some updates in `.htaccess` and `index.php`

**.htaccess**

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE store
SetEnvIf Host domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=yourcode
SetEnvIf Host domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=yourcode
```

**index.php**

insert the code bellow right before this: `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'domain.com':
    case 'www.domain.com':
        $mageRunCode = 'code';
        $mageRunType = 'website';
    break;
    case 'domain2.com':
    case 'www.domain2.com':
        $mageRunCode = 'code';
        $mageRunType = 'website';
    break;
}
```